# how to capture bootstrap modal open/close event in meteor js

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I am trying to capture bootstrap modal open/close event in meteor js to do some custom checks. I know how to do it in jquery:

```
$('#videoCallModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

but since I also want to refer the context (this object), I want to do it in Template.template.events.

I tried something like, but the function was not invoked:

```
Template.videoCall.events = {
    'on #videoCallModal shown.bs.modal': function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log("modal open", this);
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to capture the close/open of modal in meteor js

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```js
Template.videoCall.events({
  'shown.bs.modal #videoCallModal': function(e){
    /* ... */
  }
});
```

See this [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/k6yiBeZ7TtX3FTiE2).

Answer (score 6):

I created [peppelg:bootstrap-3-modal](https://atmospherejs.com/peppelg/bootstrap-3-modal) to provide a simple way to handle modals in Meteor. With it, you can use the `created` and `destroyed` callbacks (just as your used to in Meteor!), instead of the open and close events.

Comment: Will this not work for versions below 0.9.0? I have not moved my code to 0.9.0 yet.

Comment: @AashuAgarwal, I'm sorry, but you can't install the package unless you're using version 0.9.1.1 or newer. However, it's not a complex package, simply copying [this HTML file](https://github.com/PeppeL-G/bootstrap-3-modal/blob/master/main.html) and [this JavaScript file](https://github.com/PeppeL-G/bootstrap-3-modal/blob/master/main.js) to your meteor project may make it work, depending on which version of Meteor you're using. The only things you might have trouble with are `UI.dynamic`, `Blaze.renderWithData` and `Blaze.remove` (depending on your Meteor version).

Comment: after trying so many different packages for meteor boostrap modals peppelg:bootstrap-3-modal  ended up being the simplest to use. awesome job